# Why is cross entropy loss averaged and not used directly as a sum during model training(such as in neural networks)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function, gradient-descent, cross-entropy

Why is the cross entropy loss for all training examples(or the training examples in a batch) averaged over size of the training set(or batch size) ?

Why is it not just summed and used ?

Answer (score 2):

Sum depends on the number of data points, obviously. It is still valid and often used (e.g. when comparable scales in a custom compound loss are needed), assuming the most popular implementations of minibatch learning. The main benefit of averaging is bringing the loss to a uniform scale. This allows:

- loss interpretation, to a certain extent;
- easy evaluation of models trained with different hyperparameters against each other;
- the last batch of the training set, which might be shorter than others, having the same contribution to loss;
- optimal regularization amount and learning rate being much less dependent on batch size.